# How to transpose dataframe without any aggregation in pandas & R?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, reshape, transpose

I have the below dataframe.

```
user_id item_id rank
user1   item4   1
user1   item2   2
user1   item5   3
user1   item1   4
user1   item3   5
user2   item5   1
user2   item3   2
user2   item4   3
user2   item1   4
user2   item2   5
```

How to reshape to the below format in both R & pandas?

```
user_id rank1   rank2   rank3   rank4   rank5
user1   item4   item2   item5   item1   item3
user2   item5   item3   item4   item1   item2
```

I am finding transpose especially in R tricky. Any elegant standard function/way which work all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `library(reshape2)` in `R` to convert the 'long' format to 'wide' format

```
library(reshape2) 
dcast(df1, user_id~paste0('rank', rank), value.var='item_id')
#   user_id rank1 rank2 rank3 rank4 rank5
#1   user1 item4 item2 item5 item1 item3
#2   user2 item5 item3 item4 item1 item2
```

Comment: If I want to sum the values of value.var will dcast still work? How specify the aggregate function?

Comment: @mrcet007 You can specify the `fun.aggregate` i.e. `dcast(df1, user_id~paste0('rank', rank), value.var='item_id', sum)`.  In the example, the `item_id` is 'character', so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pivot in pandas. e.g. (after saving your data in 'data.txt')

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='rank', values='item_id')
```

Comment: Thanks I tried pivot_table()  and got error saying cannot aggregate . What is the difference between the two?

Comment: when run the code with pivot() i am getting the below error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: `pivot` uses a default aggregate `mean` and thus will not work on text column.